# Print previous line when a "match" found: Pyspark

Tags: pyspark

I would like to display a line before the matched string.
I know how to use it using "GREP" but I wanted the same using pyspark.
Could you please let me now if we can do this using pyspark.

```
grep -B
```

I use below code to search for the matched string

```
df.filter(F.col('string').contains('start'))
```

In the below example input is the dataframe which contains 4 lines.
When I search for the keyword "start", I would like to get the output with line "start" and also the previous line.

example:

```
input
2021-08-30 end active
2021-09-01 end inactive
2021-09-02 start active
2021-09-03  end   active

**Expected output:**
2021-09-01 end inactive
2021-09-02 start active
```

Comment: Can you explain your expected output a bit more?

Comment: @RobertKossendey

Comment: In general Spark dataframes are unordered and there is no guranteed _prevoius line_. One option would be to use a ordered [Window](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.Window.html), but you would need a column that defines the order of the rows.